# collapsing toolbar wont move when scrolling

Tags: android, layout

i have a little issue with a collapsing toolbar, the problem is that when i touch the bellow part the collapsing toolbar wont move only the layout under the collapsing toolbar. Only when i touch the collapsing toolbar moves, PLEASE i need to the collapsing toolbar to get smaller when the bellow layout moves down, (attached is the content layout)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/White"
    tools:context=".Contrinfo">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ci_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ci_collapsiing_tooolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/profilePrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@id/ci_toolbar"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ci_back"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/t_ci_t"
                    style="@style/profileStyledBackButton" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:id="@+id/ci_toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>



    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/ci_content_main"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the content main is:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/lp_frame_layout"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_contrinfo"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Contrinfo">

<LinearLayout
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/celeste"
android:orientation="vertical">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_ci_nit"
        style="@style/text_ci"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_ci_txt_nit"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="-2"
        android:shadowDy="-2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_ci_nit"
        style="@style/text_ci"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_ci_nit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_ci_nit"
        android:text="4824989011"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="-2"
        android:shadowDy="-2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_ci_vencimiento_tit"
        style="@style/text_ci"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/val_ci_nit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/str_ci_txt_vm"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/val_ci_vencimiento_tit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/cpb_3"
        android:layout_height="180dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_ic_vencimiento"
        style="@style/text_ci"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/val_ci_vencimiento_tit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="-4"
        android:shadowDy="-4"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textSize="80sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/txt_ci_counter"
    style="@style/text_ci"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_ci_txt_t1"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ci_d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/val_ci_cd"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            style="@style/text_ci_counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="-4"
            android:shadowDy="-4"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:textSize="45sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/txt_ci_cd"
            style="@style/text_ci"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/val_ci_cd"
            android:text="@string/str_ci_txt_d"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ci_h"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rl_ci_d"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_ci_d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/val_ci_ch"
            style="@style/text_ci_counter"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="18"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="-4"
            android:shadowDy="-4"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:textSize="45sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_ci_ch"
            style="@style/text_ci"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/val_ci_ch"
            android:text="@string/str_ci_txt_h"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/val_ic_obli1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/val_ic_obli2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/val_ic_obli3"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    style="@style/text_ci"
    android:id="@+id/txt_ci_ti"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/str_ci_txt_ti"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="dsadasdsadsad"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="dsadasdsadsad"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="dsadasdsadsad"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="dsadasdsadsad"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

change you `ci_content_main.xml` parent tag from `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works just fine, appreciate the help very much, sorry for not score you, i can't yet